# restrict access to s3 objects via policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am having issues with controlling access to s3 objects with policies.

The setup is

- Cognito user
- Identity Pool - attached to Cognito
- Within the identity pool I have an authenticated role which has the following policy attached:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  SAM Template for roles

#
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  RolesIAM:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Federated:
                - "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx"
              ForAnyValue:StringLike:
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
      Description: "Role for Cognito access"
      RoleName: "Cognito_Role"

  PropVoltPolicyIAM:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: "UploadS3Policy"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "s3:ListBucket"
            Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket name>"
            Condition:
              StringLike:
                's3:prefix': "cognito/application-name/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
              - "s3:PutObject"
              - "s3:DeleteObject"
            Resource:
              - "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket name>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
              - "arn:aws:s3:::<Bucket name>/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RolesIAM
```

So I have an express server running in lambda which does the `putObject` like so:

```
app.post("/api/upload/add", upload.single('uploadedFile'), async(req, res) => {
  const token = getAccessToken(req.headers.authorization);

  const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
  const sub = decodedToken.sub;

  const params = {Bucket:<Bucket name>', Key: `${sub}/${req.body.propertyId}/${req.file.originalname}`, Body: req.file.buffer, ACL: 'private'};
  
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("error===", err)
    if(!err) {
      console.log("no error");
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The issue is that it let's you upload even if I amend the policy.

Comment: How do you construct the `s3` client object? It would presumably be using credentials from the IAM Role that is assigned to the AWS Lambda function, which seems to have permission to write to S3. Where in your code is the IAM Role assigned by Cognito being used?

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about this yesterday as it's in a lambda it would assume the role. The construct in the lambda is: const s3 = new aws.S3();. Would i be able to check the permissions based on the cognito identity id maybe and some how check on the putobject? Would i be able disallow lambda access but allow temporary access for the user instead?

Comment: If you want to manage uploads to S3, the normal method would be to [Upload objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). This presigned URL can be produced by your back-end. Alternatively, the front-end could use the credentials provided by Cognito to perform the upload direct to S3. I don't think you actually need to upload via an AWS Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks. I am using lambda as need to do some extra work such as updating dB etc

Comment: I am struggling on this as i do not want to pass the signedurl back to client and then do some more processing again in the backend. Not sure the best way for this?